# How do I mount a second ceiling light from the same junction box

Tags: wiring, lighting, junction-box

Have an existing ceiling fixture (*pendant*) that is wired to a switch. I'm interested in wiring another light to the same fixture, A simple track light like [this](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/tross-ceiling-track-3-spotlights-white-80262663/) one.

I understand that as per code, all connections need to be made inside a junction box. Trying to think of a creative way that I can wire this light (*or a similar light*) into the existing light on the ceiling while keeping  the current pendant.

One thought was running conduit from the box, and then externally mounting another box for the new light. I-realize this is not a very elegant or aesthetic solution but that is not what most concerns me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use surface mounted box's and raceway.

You would need one [box extension](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Wiremold-500-700-1-Piece-Ivory-Raceway-Extension-Box/3152509) on the existing box, this will allow you mount your pendent and then run a [raceway](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Legrand-11-Piece-7-5-in-x-White-Cord-Cable-Organization-Kit/1001340326), containing the wiring, to a second [surface mounted box](https://www.lowes.com/pd/MonoSystems-CableHider-Ultra-1-Piece-White-Raceway-Electrical-Box/1018141).

The examples i linked to are all not the same brand, just examples to illustrate what i am talking about. If you go to the home centers electrical dept you will find a section containing these types of products in various brands, sizes and parts to allow you to configure any type of surface mounted raceway/box's.

Of coarse you will need wire, wire nuts, tools and the **appropriate knowledge** to work with electricity in order to **do it safely**.

Answer (score 1):

That junction box looks like it sits below the ceiling ~2” with that space I would notch for a surface mount wireway square in shape or punch a hole for a 1/2” conduit and run to another surface mount box and suspend the pendant light from that, all the splices would be in boxes accessible and be code compliant.